How to create a tabs with a centered indicator and real indicator position in jetpack compose
I tried to create a tabs in jetpack compose But I cannot control all the properties of the tabs
i want to change the indicator color , height and corner radius
i want to make the indicator to move in the real position of the pager in the same time
var selectedTabIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
// ...
TabRow(selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex) {}

HorizontalPager(
state = pagerState,
modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .weight(1f)
 ) {} 

Tabs which i want to do
